# Running an app in HTML

Tags: android, html

I am asking if it's possible and if so, how you would go about running an Android app within a HTML container.

For example, I go on a website an an APK starts running within the website.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No, it's not possible. APKs don't run in an HTML container.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of Service providers who provided Live android device on web

Some are:
https://appetize.io/

http://runthatapp.com/

https://testobject.com/